# asp.net how to implement Chat between site users?

Tags: asp.net, chat

Is there a relative easy way to implement Chat?

Is it possible to integrate Microsoft Messenger in a web site?

Or maybe there is a good free plugin for chat?

(I'm using Asp.net 3.5 + JQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Google chat
http://googletalk.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-talk-chatback.html